# Why privileges on SYSTEM

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I'm trying LiquiBase, so for testing I created new schema/user LB_TEST

```sql
create user LB_TEST identified by <password>;

grant create session, connect, resource to LB_TEST;

alter user LB_TEST default tablespace USERS;

alter user LB_TEST quota 10M on USERS;

alter USER LB_TEST TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
```

but when I executed LiquiBase I'm getting

```
c:\betlista\progs\\liquibase-3.8.7>liquibase.bat --defaultsFile=lb_test.properties update
Liquibase Community 3.8.7 by Datical
Unexpected error running Liquibase: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSTEM'
 [Failed SQL: (1950) INSERT INTO LB_TEST.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, 0)]
For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
```

I do understand what the error is saying, but I do not understand, why I need privileges on `SYSTEM` TS.

**edit:**

## lb_test.properties

```
# SQL change log
#changeLogFile: c:/betlista/Git/LiquiBase-tests/changelog.sql
# XML change log
changeLogFile: c:/betlista/Git/LiquiBase-tests/changelog.xml

driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/MDMDEV
username: lb_test
password: <password>

#defaultSchemaName=lb_test

classpath: c:/betlista/progs/no-install/liquibase-3.8.7/drivers/ojdbc7.jar
```

I didn't add this as obviously there is no problem connecting to DB...

Comment: SQL Developer latest version includes LiquBase.  I reccomend following their instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the info, might be useful, but my goal is automation and for that, I need to be able to run from command line.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `connect` role already includes `create session` so there is no need to grant both.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the content of `lb_test.properties`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added

Comment: SQL Developer has command line interface for LiquiBase.

Comment: I don't think this is related, but the JDBC URL looks strange. You are mixing the old deprecated syntax connecting to a SID with the new (and recommended) syntax. It should either be: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/mdmdev` (note the `@//`) or `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:MDMDEV`  but I don't think that's the reason for the error. Do you have any logon triggers maybe?

Comment: Simplest explanation: The table `LB_TEST.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` was created in the `SYSTEM` tablespace. The table could be created in `SYSTEM` tablespace even though `LB_TEST` has no quota on that due to deferred segment creation. That is why it did not get an error when the table was created, but it got an error on the first `INSERT` attempt.